# How do I escape symbol in shell script?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I want to write text to other file using shell script `echo` but data is not being written in exact format as i intent

```
echo paste B01_reprojected_subset_comma_updated.csv  B02_reprojected_subset_comma_updated.csv B03_reprojected_subset_comma_updated.csv B04_reprojected_subset_comma_updated.csv B05_reprojected_subset_comma_updated.csv B06_reprojected_subset_comma_updated.csv B07_reprojected_subset_comma_updated.csv B08_reprojected_subset_comma_updated.csv B8A_reprojected_subset_comma_updated.csv B09_reprojected_subset_comma_updated.csv B10_reprojected_subset_comma_updated.csv B11_reprojected_subset_comma_updated.csv B12_reprojected_subset_comma_updated.csv |awk -F",||\t" '{print  $1","$2","$3","$6","$9","$12","$15","$18","$21","$24","$27","$30","$33","$36","$39}'>allbands.csv >> jobstext.sh
```

but i am getting text like this in jobstext.sh

```
paste B01_reprojected_subset_comma_updated.csv B02_reprojected_subset_comma_updated.csv B03_reprojected_subset_comma_updated.csv B04_reprojected_subset_comma_updated.csv B05_reprojected_subset_comma_updated.csv B06_reprojected_subset_comma_updated.csv B07_reprojected_subset_comma_updated.csv B08_reprojected_subset_comma_updated.csv B8A_reprojected_subset_comma_updated.csv B09_reprojected_subset_comma_updated.csv B10_reprojected_subset_comma_updated.csv B11_reprojected_subset_comma_updated.csv B12_reprojected_subset_comma_updated.csv,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

i have tried to escape special symbol but still data is not in exact format.

can anybody help me do this?

```
paste B01_reprojected_subset_comma_updated.csv B02_reprojected_subset_comma_updated.csv B03_reprojected_subset_comma_updated.csv B04_reprojected_subset_comma_updated.csv B05_reprojected_subset_comma_updated.csv B06_reprojected_subset_comma_updated.csv B07_reprojected_subset_comma_updated.csv B08_reprojected_subset_comma_updated.csv B8A_reprojected_subset_comma_updated.csv B09_reprojected_subset_comma_updated.csv B10_reprojected_subset_comma_updated.csv B11_reprojected_subset_comma_updated.csv B12_reprojected_subset_comma_updated.csv |awk -F",||\t" '{print  $1","$2","$3","$6","$9","$12","$15","$18","$21","$24","$27","$30","$33","$36","$39}'>allbands1.csv
```

Comment: I see a missing `"` before `$1` and  after `$39` check that!

Comment: @George it is in right format  i want to write data in same format..  :)

Comment: Can you give us an example of how it's supposed to look like in the output ?

Comment: Do you want to escape the dollar signs? Then put a backslash in front of it. Furthermore I see: ` > allbands.csv >> jobstext.sh `. That will leave you with an empty jobstext.sh all the time.

Comment: If you want it exactly as you wrote it, quote everything with single quotes `echo 'any $tring with a\\ weird "special" chars except for single quotes' > yourfile

Comment: Do you want the contents of the files reformatted or just the filenames?  As it stands you are echoing the text "paste" followed by a list of filenames into an awk which will reformat that text, but not read anything from the files themselves.  Also note that finishing with two redirections for stdout will not likely do what you expect.

Comment: @Philippos i have updated my ans

Comment: @gauravsingh: pay attention to the first 2 lines of Jeffrey Ross' comment.

Comment: @JeffreyRoss I dont want to refomart  the content i just i want to print the data to other file  content which are left side of >> shuld be printend into jobstext.sh file ..

Answer (score 1):

To keep the shell from touching your text (including special chars like `$` and `>` or `*`, put everything in single quotes. To include single quotes in the string you have to interrupt the quoted string and add a backslash-escaped single quote resulting in `'here comes the embedded '\''quote'`:

```
echo 'paste B01_reprojected_subset_comma_updated.csv  B02_reprojected_subset_comma_updated.csv B03_reprojected_subset_comma_updated.csv B04_reprojected_subset_comma_updated.csv B05_reprojected_subset_comma_updated.csv B06_reprojected_subset_comma_updated.csv B07_reprojected_subset_comma_updated.csv B08_reprojected_subset_comma_updated.csv B8A_reprojected_subset_comma_updated.csv B09_reprojected_subset_comma_updated.csv B10_reprojected_subset_comma_updated.csv B11_reprojected_subset_comma_updated.csv B12_reprojected_subset_comma_updated.csv |awk -F",||\t" '\''{print  $1","$2","$3","$6","$9","$12","$15","$18","$21","$24","$27","$30","$33","$36","$39}'\''>allbands.csv' >> jobstext.sh
```

Comment: You can't escape `'` within a single-quoted string

Comment: @muru Thank you. Somehow I did believe I always did it this way, but obviously not in the shell. Learned something and fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier if you split up the printing and used `printf` format strings to arrange the output. First, the paste command, taking advantage of brace expansion:

```
printf "%s " paste B{01..12}_reprojected_subset_comma_updated.csv >> jobstext.sh
```

Then, the awk command, simplified by using OFS:

```
printf "| %s '%s' %s %s '%s' > %s\n" awk -F',|\t' -v OFS=, '{print $1, $2, $3, $6, $9, $12, $15, $18, $21, $24, $27, $30, $33, $36, $39}' allbands1.csv >> jobstext.sh
```

You can also use `%q` to simplify the format strings used for `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

Without a sample of your files or a clear description of what you want to do or the desired format of the output file this is mere guesswork.  Perhaps you want to append a command line (paste stuff|awk action) to file jobstext.sh.  That would be better done by using an editor to avoid the nested quote issues...

But your question asks about escaping special characters so to answer that one option is to encapsulate a single quote within double quotes.  Abbreviating your lengthy filenames down to B01, etc, this would look as below.

```
echo 'paste B01 B02 B03 B04 B05 B06 B07 B08 B8A B09 B10 B11 B12 |
awk -F",||\t" '"'"'{print "$1","$2","$3","$6","$9","$12","$15","$18","$21",
"$24","$27","$30","$33","$36","$39}'"'"' >allbands.csv' >> jobstext.sh
```

The first single quote starts a string that includes the paste command, filenames, pipe, awk and F option.  Then the first single quote of the `'"'"'` sequence closes the string, the next 3 characters define another string of a single quote, and the final character is a single quote starting a third string (that includes the awk action in braces).  A similar 5 quote sequence closes that string, inserts another single quote, and starts the fifth string (which consists of redirecting the output into allbands.csv).  Finally that string is closed (with the last quote of the line), so all 5 strings are concatenated and appended to jobstext.sh.

This is cumbersome, but that's what comes of trying to use two levels of single quoting on one command line.  The single quotes are required to prevent the awk statement from being interpreted by the shell.

Improvements would be 1/ to use filenames that could be expanded with `*` (but your "B8A" introduces an inconsistency that prevents simple filename expansion), and 2/ to simplify the command by editing it into jobstext.sh.  The suggestions in @muru's answer are worth incorporating (but take care with that "B8A" file!)